# URL rewriting/redirecting with two parameters

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, redirect

Basically, I want to have this URL:

```
http://domain.tld/auth.php?state=somestate&token=somelongtoken
```

rewritten/redirected into this:

```
http://domain.tld/auth/validate/somestate/somelongtoken
```

I have been looking over the net for quite some time now, but I cannot figure out how to do this thing..

Also - would a redirect or a rewrite be the best here?

I am not going to use the URL for anything other than validating a user from a API, so it is just redirecting the user after visiting that page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some untested code...

```
# Make sure you are accessing auth.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/auth.php$
# Check that state and token are present (in that order...)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} state=[^&]*token=
# Rewrite the URI
RewriteRule ^/auth.php\?state=\([^&]*\)\&token=\([^&]*\)$ auth/validate/\1/\2 [L,QSA]
```

I would use a rewrite since you're saying that /auth.php will do a Location: already. There is really no point in sending two redirect. Plus that's bad practice with search engines (I know in this case it won't happen, just mentioning, because if it is bad for SEO, it's probably not that nice for your users.)

Note that the regex of the RewriteRule and previous conditions expects those two query string parameters to be in that very order. You'd need multiple lines to not force the order. But I would imagine that it isn't a problem.

Comment: Thanks. The parameters will always be in that order, so that shouldn't be an issue.
However, I decided to go with a php file that does the redirect, but will let this one be the accepted answer, since it answers my original question.